# VS Code Mac not Using SFDX Commands

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I'm currently trying to troubleshoot something wrong with my vscode.

I'm able to us Salesforce DX CLI tools in the console, but I'm not able to do it with the `Command + P + >`. Whenever I do this, I only get three options (see screen shot).

This was from a github repo for the salesforce Dream house app.

I believe it has something to do with my bin files, but I'm not sure what or how to begin troubleshooting.

Any help would be really appreciated.

### Things attempted:

1. Uninstalled and re-installed Salesforce CLI.
2. Added my Java instance to the salesforce settings.
3. Checked my $PATH, it appears to be pointing to a composer file for laravel, but not sure how to change it back if this is needs to be pointing at something else.

[image]

Comment: Restarting vs code resolved this issue when I faced it many months ago. I suppose you already tried restarting? You can also try creating org project (by connecting to existing org) at exact same location which would trigger the sf cli commands to show up

Comment: I tried restarting VS Code: still getting Command 'SFDX: Create Project' resulted in an error (command 'sfdx.force.project.create' not found). I connected tho an existing org, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'exact same location'. I used the dreamhouse git repository from Salesforce and connected to trailhead org, but still can't create projects.

Comment: @salesforce-sas can you give more context for the meaning of 'exact same location' are you saying folder location? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, After you clone git repository in folder A, this folder may not have sfdx files. So, you can create `SFDX: create project` (which opens wizard to connect to org) and select same folder A to create project after which you should see all SFDX commands. Not sure why SFDX create project would give error. It should work from any location though. Check if your sfdx CLI is fine in this case.

Comment: Try updating VS Code and restarting the VS Code app. This solved it for me just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work, but had to uninstall CLI and delete vsCode extensions.

Here are the steps that I did.

1. Show Hidden Files in Finder (could have removed the folders for the extensions in iterm, but decided to use the GUI).
2. navigate to your .vscode/extensions folder and then delete all the salesforce extensions folders (they should all begin with `salsforce-`
3. Then I followed Salesforce [UnInstall Steps for the Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm)
4. I restarted VS Code, and verified that no Salesforce Commands were coming in to VS Code's command palette (e.g. Create Project, Create Project with Manifest etc).
5. [Used NPM to install the CLI globally:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm) Might have to scroll down a bit to see the steps.
6. Updated CLI vi NPM
7. Then I went through the [trailhead to setup VSCode with Salesforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/vscode-salesforce-ready):
8. After completing that trailhead (which has you reinstall the extensions) I was able to get VS code synced up and command palette was working again.

Comment: Got the delete extension folders idea from a recent github post. Will try and find it again and post here.

Comment: Life saver! Thanks!